# Find out version of all xorg components

Tags: shell, xorg

I try to find out the version of installed xorg components.

Sadly, many of these components don't have `--version` or `-version`. Only a few do.

`xkill -version` does not work nor does `xkill --version`.

On IRC, alanc said this:

> I've been adding -version or similar flags to many of the X.Org
>   apps as time allows, but haven't finished them all yet
>
> the
>   simplest way remains to query the package system used to install them
>
> also we try to include version info in the man pages
>
> `xmore` is a bad example as it's been abandoned for years though

Here is the list I have compiled so far: http://pastie.org/pastes/9515733/text

Is there some way to find out the version? Perhaps I can parse the man page from within a script, but how? Or perhaps some flag or version bytes are set in the binary itself?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could specify a distribution. Some distributions have package managers that will output installed packages with the current version number.

Comment: In addition, many of the x... components/utilities/drivers are packaged together and share a common version or release. This is also distribution dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You will often find the versions in the binaries themselves using a command like the following:

```
strings $(which xkill) | egrep -i "ver|OSF|\d\.\d"
```

though having just checked my Ubuntu installation I didn't find much :-(